# Share Buttons by AddThis NOTICE: wp-content/plugins/addthis/addthis-toolbox.php:130 - Undefined variable

Tags: wordpress, variables, undefined

I have the following problem with Wordpress. How can I fix this ?

> NOTICE: wp-content/plugins/addthis/addthis-toolbox.php:130 - Undefined variable: inputHtml
>
> require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/myTheme/index.php'), get_sidebars, get_sidebar, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/myTheme/sidebar-right.php'), Popular_posts, get_the_excerpt, apply_filters('get_the_excerpt'), call_user_func_array, Addthis_ToolBox->addWidgetForExcerpt, Addthis_ToolBox->addWidget
>
> NOTICE: wp-content/plugins/addthis/addthis-toolbox.php:136 - Undefined variable: inputHtml
>
> require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/myTheme/index.php'), get_sidebars, get_sidebar, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/myThemesidebar-right.php'), Popular_posts, get_the_excerpt, apply_filters('get_the_excerpt'), call_user_func_array, Addthis_ToolBox->addWidgetForExcerpt, Addthis_ToolBox->addWidget

// Wordpress verson 4.4
// 130 line:

```
if (isset($aboveDivClass)
              && strpos($inputHtml, $htmlComments['above']['search']) === false
          ) {
              $content  = $htmlComments['above']['comment'] . self::_buildDiv($aboveDivClass) . $content;
          }
```

// line 136:

```
  && strpos($inputHtml, $htmlComments['below']['search']) === false
) {
    $content .= $htmlComments['below']['comment'];
    $content .= self::_buildDiv($belowDivClass);
}
```